# How to convert a string to Blob in web_sys?

Tags: rust, web-sys

I am trying to convert a string to blob using [web_sys](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.Blob.html#method.new_with_str_sequence)

```rust
let json_string = json::stringify(data);
let json_jsvalue = JsValue::from_str(&json_string);

let json_blob_result = Blob::new_with_str_sequence(&json_jsvalue);
let json_blob = json_blob_result.unwrap();
```

It gives error:

panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: JsValue(TypeError: Blob constructor: Argument 1 can't be converted to a sequence.

Comment: You should read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#creating_a_blob) first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As explained in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#creating_a_blob), to create a `Blob` from string you need to wrap it in array:

```rust
let json_string = json::stringify(data);
let json_jsvalue = JsValue::from_str(&json_string);
let json_jsvalue_array = js_sys::Array::from_iter(std::iter::once(json_jsvalue));

let json_blob_result = Blob::new_with_str_sequence(&json_jsvalue_array);
let json_blob = json_blob_result.unwrap();
```